# What better way to run PushSharp?

Tags: .net, mobile, push-notification, pushsharp

I am learning to PushSharp. What better way to perform and why?

- Windows Service?
- Simple ConsoleApp?
- WCF HTTP Activation?
- Other?

I searched for similar problems but have not found answer. I need the opinion of someone who uses the PushSharp in production for some app with many users (over 10,000 members, for example).

Answer (score 2):

We're using it in production but not for that large scale. Currently, for a closed beta app and 50-100 clients. You can fork/check my repo on **https://github.com/vmandic/DevUG-PushSharp** where I demonstrated **different approaches in the implementation which you suggested, such as a WinForms and WebAPI processors.** There should be no problems with **PushSharp** itself because it's only a wrapper around a bounch of http requests.

The problem could arise from the Apple/Google/Microsoft notifications service endpoints not handling a lot of PNs fast or correctly. PushSharp should enqueue messages correctly!

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vedran!

I'm using the WebAPI for process the notifications.

Cheers!